# Set PhantomJS to capture entire screen after using clipRect()

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen-scraping, phantomjs

After doing setting `page.clipRect` followed by `page.render`,  how can you disable `clipRect` so that subsequent page renders are of the entire viewport?

```
page.clipRect = {top:0, left:0, height: 10, width: 10} ;
page.render('screencap.png');  // cropped image

page.clipRect = '';
page.render('fullscreen.png');  // still cropped image!
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply reset all values for `clipRect`:

```
page.clipRect = { left:0, top:0, width:0, height:0 }
```

then PhantomJS will recapture the entire content again.

Comment: Isn't it cool when the creator of the software himself answers the question? I think is cool.